# FusionAuth Authorization

Tags: java, spring, fusionauth

I am developing a Spring Boot REST API, this API exposes a "/verify" endpoint to validate the token and the access to a certain resource. In FusionAuth I have roles attached to my users. So is the a method to validate if the user has that role so i can let them pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FusionAuth, the access token is a JWT, which contains a JSON payload like this:

```
{
  "applicationId": "3c219e58-ed0e-4b18-ad48-f4f92793ae32",
  // ...
  "roles": [
    "necessary_role",
    "other_role"
  ],
  // ...
}
```

To get that JSON out of the JWT, you can [decode it yourself](https://www.lenar.io/how-to-decode-jwt-authentication-token/) or pass it to one of a few FusionAuth endpoints that will return readable JSON:

- [Introspect](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/oauth/endpoints#introspect) `/oauth2/introspect`
- [UserInfo](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/oauth/endpoints#userinfo) `/oauth2/userinfo`
- [Validate](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/jwt#validate-a-jwt) `/api/jwt/validate`

Once you have readable JSON, you just need to examine the `roles` array for the role in question:

```java
if (jwt.roles.contains("necessary_role") {
  // handle user with necessary_role
} else {
  // handle user without necessary_role
}
```